# Not able understand the use of | operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to java-script and not able to understand the use of | operator in following code snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a number between 0 and 1</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
     var a=Math.random();
     var x = ((a*2 | 0));  
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; 

}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's a bit operator.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/bitwise-or-operator-decrement-javascript

Comment: Thank you guys now i got how the code is working.

Answer (score 1):

That's [bitwise OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR)

> Performs the OR operation on each pair of bits. a OR b yields 1 if either a or b is 1. The truth table for the OR operation is:

Bitwise ORing any number x with 0 yields x. Bitwise ORing any number x with -1 yields -1.